# Python global variable

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, global

```
def say_boo_twice():
  global boo
  boo = 'Boo!'
  print boo, boo

boo = 'boo boo'
say_boo_twice()
```

The output is

> Boo! Boo!

Not as I expected. Since I declared `boo` as global, why is the output not:

> boo boo boo boo

Comment: That's the expected output. You assign boo, then you print it twice.

Comment: this is a confusing example. why not change the values rather than "say twice" for "boo boo"? muddy thinking.

Comment: It's unclear why this question was asked, let alone how it got upvotes and an answer. Why should it matter whether `boo` is local or global - **how is it surprising** that assigning to a name and then immediately using it, results in the newly assigned value being used? I can't understand the logic behind expecting what OP expected.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You've changed `boo` inside your function, why wouldn't it change? Also, global variables are bad.

Comment: instead of using global variables, what are the better way to handle a variable to be used across functions?

Comment: @NicholasTJ You should ask that as a new question. I guess you could store the "global" variables in a Singleton class, or a module's dictionary - also see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6255050/321973)

Comment: I don't know a way to use matplotlib directly without globals and side effects and order-dependent, imperative ooze. I'd suppose that Python programmers just get accustomed to that style from using matplotlib.

Comment: are such "global" variables local to the module, or the whole system?

Comment: why `global` variables are bad? @Dr McKay

Answer (score 18):

Because you reassign right before hand.  Comment out `boo = 'Boo!'` and you will get what you describe.

```
def say_boo_twice():
   global boo
   #boo = 'Boo!'
   print boo, boo  

boo = 'boo boo' 
say_boo_twice()
```

Also that `global boo` is unnecessary, `boo` is already in global scope.
This is where the `global` makes a difference

```
def say_boo_twice():   
   global boo
   boo = 'Boo!'
   print boo, boo  

say_boo_twice() 
print "outside the function: " + boo #works
```

Whereas:

```
def say_boo_twice():   
   #global boo
   boo = 'Boo!'
   print boo, boo  

say_boo_twice() 
print "outside the function: " + boo # ERROR.  boo is only known inside function, not to this scope
```

Answer (score 5):

You are re-assigning boo after you declare it as global, so the value is the last one you assigned to it. If you removed line three, you would get the output you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you reassign boo when you call the function.

Check how this works with the globals() and locals() functions.

Answer (score 0):

Before giving an example I want you to understand difference between global and local variable in python

**global variable:** This is specific to current module

**local variable:** This is specific to current functions or methods as we call it in python

**What if both local and current variable have the same name boo ?**

In such case if you don't define your **variable boo as global** in the same method or function it will by default use it as **local variable**

**Coming to your code**

You have defined boo as global in your method **say_boo_twice()**.
The catch is when you try to initialize **boo = 'Boo!'** in that method you are actually overwriting what you initialized previously as boo = 'boo boo'

**Try this code**

-- I have not initialized variable boo inside method **say_boo_twice()**

```
def say_boo_twice():    
    global boo
    print boo, boo

boo = 'boo boo'    
say_boo_twice()
```

All the Best !!! !! !

Answer (score 0):

global boo is global only inside method say_boo_twice and has been re-assigned a value inside of this method. You need to understand the lexical or scope where it can be global or what you want it to be. In this context, just before printing, it was assigned a value of 'Boo!' and that is what it correctly printed.